# Finding a Basis for the 5x5 solutions space W

Tags: linear-algebra

I have here W:

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 &  1 & 7 & 1 & 2 \\
0 &  1 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
0 &  0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
2 &  1 & 6 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4 \\
x_5
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

(Im sorry i dont know how to form matrices in here so i just wrote down these)

To find the basis, I first reduced W.
And after some bloody reducing with 5x5, i found the reduced form of W:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 &  0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &  2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &  0 & 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$

so i got my solution set:
\begin{array}{rcr}
x_1 & = &-  e \\
x_2 & = &   e \\
x_3 & = &   0 \\
x_4 & = & -2e \\
x_5 & = &   e 
\end{array}

and my conclusion:
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4 \\
x_5
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 -e \\
  e \\
  0 \\
-2e \\
  e 
\end{array}
\right]
=
e
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
-1 \\
 1 \\
 0 \\
-2 \\
 1 
\end{array}
\right]
$$

The problem is that, i'm missing 1 basis.
In the book the basis are = {[-2,-2,1,0,0],[-1,1,0,-2,1]}

As you can see, i got the second basis. but what about the first? am i missing something?

Comment: The system and conclusion seem right, check the reduction of the matrix

Comment: my solution for reduction is correct. i double checked it online with http://matrix.reshish.com/gaussSolution.php

Comment: I checked it too.  Your solution and answer are correct which means that there is an error in your text.

Comment: @user66240, why did you conclude that $x_5=e$?

Comment: @Galc127, its not part of the conclusion. i just changed the variables form the solution set just to make it clear.

Comment: well since X_5 is undefined i just assumed that e is any real number

Comment: That's (more or less) right: in the way you wrote your solution, $x_5$ can be any real number. That is: all the other variables can be expressed in term of this $x_5 = e$ and for every $e$, you have a solution. This infinite number of solutions is spanned by the one vector you put in the basis. Your solution is correct!